# Cannot compile this poco program

Tags: c++, linux, installation, poco, poco-libraries

I cloned poco library from github and I executed the file *build_cmake.sh* which was present in the repo. There weren't any problems during the execution of the *build_cmake.sh* file.It created a lot of header files in the /usr/local/include directory.

```cpp
#include "Poco/DateTime.h"
#include "Poco/Timespan.h"
#include<iostream>
using Poco::DateTime;
using Poco::Timespan;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        // what is my age?
        DateTime birthdate(1995, 02, 16, 2, 30); // 1973-09-12 02:30:00 //date of birth 
                                 //and time in following format YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss


        DateTime now;

        Timespan age = now - birthdate;
        int days = age.days(); // in days
        int hours = age.totalHours(); // in hours
        int secs = age.totalSeconds(); // in seconds

        cout << "iNDays: You are  " << days << " days older." << endl;
        cout << "iNHours: You are " << hours << " hours older. " << endl;
        cout << "iNSeconds: You are " << secs << " seconds older" << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Now if I compile this file using

```sh
g++ filename.cpp
```

I get the following error.

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc187sFs.o: in function `main':
timeSpace.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `Poco::DateTime::DateTime(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: timeSpace.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `Poco::DateTime::DateTime()'
/usr/bin/ld: timeSpace.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `Poco::DateTime::operator-(Poco::DateTime const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: timeSpace.cpp:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `Poco::DateTime::~DateTime()'
/usr/bin/ld: timeSpace.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `Poco::DateTime::~DateTime()'
/usr/bin/ld: timeSpace.cpp:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `Poco::DateTime::~DateTime()'
/usr/bin/ld: timeSpace.cpp:(.text+0x1e2): undefined reference to `Poco::DateTime::~DateTime()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc187sFs.o: in function `Poco::Timespan::days() const':
timeSpace.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco8Timespan4daysEv[_ZNK4Poco8Timespan4daysEv]+0x12): undefined reference to `Poco::Timespan::DAYS'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc187sFs.o: in function `Poco::Timespan::totalHours() const':
timeSpace.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco8Timespan10totalHoursEv[_ZNK4Poco8Timespan10totalHoursEv]+0x12): undefined reference to `Poco::Timespan::HOURS'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc187sFs.o: in function `Poco::Timespan::totalSeconds() const':
timeSpace.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco8Timespan12totalSecondsEv[_ZNK4Poco8Timespan12totalSecondsEv]+0x12): undefined reference to `Poco::Timespan::SECONDS'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone give detailed steps for how to install the poco library and run poco programs.

Comment: How do you set the include and library paths? Where do you set the libraries? I use [Conan](http://conan.io) with CMake for Poco. It makes your life easier.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it. I am kind of new to c++ libraries I don't know much

Comment: You list the libraries with `-l` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options You have to find out which libraries you need. As I said it's much easier with Conan.

Answer (score 4):

since you have generated the POCO library, you can include the headers like this:

```
#include <Poco/DateTime.h>
```

and you should link the needed POCO library like this:

```
g++ filename.cpp -lPocoFoundation -lPocoUtil
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, this is not something easy to find in the docs. If you're trying to build something like the HTTPTimeServer sample program, you'll also need to append '-lPocoNet'.